# Inherited Control from base Form class not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have `FormBase` and `MainForm : FormBase`.

`FormBase` Contains a `DataGridView dgv`. in designer view of `FormBase` `dgv` font sizes are fine but in designer view and runtime in `MainForm` they are default values. why and what should I do??!

Comment: Mainly because the DataGridView does not support Form inheritance.

Comment: @hpt: I don't know. You need a new plan.

Comment: Maybe you can avoid form inheritance? Did you consider putting whatever UI elements you have in your BaseForm to custom user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my comment: putting UI (together with `DataGridView`) from `BaseForm` in custom user control and using it separately on previously inheriting forms will surely fix the font problem.

If your base form is only "container" for commonly used controls (so you don't have to put 3 buttons, datagrid and label on every window) or defines some basic layout - go with custom user control.

Here's decent starting point if you want to explore this topic - [Custom User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The designer for DVG doesn't support designing the control in an inherited form, a limitation of many designers of controls that were added in .NET 2.0.  The Font property is an 'ambient' property, it gets the same value as the parent unless you've explicitly selected one (shown in **bold** in the Properties window).  So either set the form's Font property to also change the DGV font or change the Font property of the DGV in the base form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach: http://dotnetengineer.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/visual-inheritance-using-datagridview/